# Story about teens with superpowers in a school

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this book when I was much younger. I remember that the main cast all had powers, I think the whole school did. The main character was a boy and he was new to the school (I think it was a school, I remember it being very prison-like). There was a guy with super strength, I think. I vividly remember a twitchy boy who could see only a few seconds into the future. The main character has the ability to read people's faces and pick apart their emotions or personality easily, I think.

Not so sure about the super strength boy. I know the main character is a boy who can read/alter emotions and a twitchy kid who can see the future only by a few seconds. That's all I'm certain about. Someone might be able to start fires but I'm not sure. Something also happens with a boat blowing up.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Edit: The character who can see a few seconds into the future.. I think his name is Twitch or Flinch or something because of his weird jumpiness.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you have a loot at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in any details you may remember. For example, you say you read it when you was younger but we don't know when that is!

Comment: Did this main character possibly have strange aunts and uncles?

Comment: @Mithrandir It's totally possible, but I don't remember.. that rings a bell sort of. Do you have a certain novel in mind?

Comment: It's kind of making me think of *Charlie Bone/The Children of the Red King*, but that doesn't match all the details.

Comment: @Mithrandir Nope, it's not that much of a fantasy book. Afaik it was as rooted in reality as a superpower book could be. I'm remembering now though that the Future Sight kid got a novel.. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Got a novel"?

Comment: Also, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125555/what-book-has-super-powered-teens-including-a-boy-with-yellow-eyes-who-can-see-a) doesn't match in many of the details, but does in a couple; could you take a look just in case?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85997/what-is-this-book-about-psychic-juvenile-delinquents

Answer (score 8):

[*Hidden Talents*](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-312-86646-4), by David Lubar.

Main character Martin, with his uncanny ability to get on people's nerves, gets thrown into a school for troubled teens.  There, he meets several other kids with special abilities:

- **Flinch,** a clairvoyant who's always on edge;
- **Torchie,** a pyrokinetic who inadvertently starts fires;
- **Cheater,** a telepath who always manages to write down the same answers on tests as his classmates;
- **Trash,** a telekinetic who accidentally "throws" things a lot;
- **Bloodbath,** a school bully with super strength

Martin himself discovers that

> he too has a superpower: he can instantly read people's character and find their flaws, which is how he's always able to say just the wrong thing to make people dislike him.

---

You might also be thinking of the sequel, [*True Talents*](https://us.macmillan.com/books/9780765379153), which focuses on "Trash" (I don't remember an exploding boat in the first one, but I never read the second).